# How to deploy WAR manually to JBOSS 5?

Tags: java, deployment, jboss, war

I've used tomcat previously for simple apps. When I needed to deploy my application I just packed it with maven to WAR file and then put that app.war to tomcat\webapps and started tomcat.
But now I need to do the same with JBOSS v.5 and I totally cannot understand the JBOSS way :(

PS: I use JBOSS through integration with my IDE but in this particular case I need manual deployment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place your application inside \server\default\deploy

and from cmd go to

```
<JBOSS_HOME>\bin
```

and execute the command

run.bat ---> to run local access only

run.bat -b 0.0.0.0 --> run in broadcast mode, (can be accessed from other system in LAN)

check your app in browser

```
http://localhost:8080/<AppName>/<Path>
```